# creating order before payment completed in ccavenue

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I am using ccacvenue payment gateway for my site. The issue is the order is getting created before the payment process starts so for failed transaction too the order is generated and customer is getting email that order is placed successfully. How to prevent the order creation for failed transaction

Help me resolve the issue

Comment: What has ccacvenue payment gateway said when you contacted them?